# How to split data with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a data like this

```
[product]
1|1|name|2.5
1|1|name|2.5
1|2|name|2.5
[category]
1|food
2|meat
[store]
1|A
2|b
```

How to split above data to an array with 3 element base on the `[{tag_name}]`. But, I don't want to specify the `{tag_name}` because it's dynamic.

Are there any good solution for this ?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen the term "slip data".

Comment: Oh it's split:D so sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this :

```
var s = "[product]\n"
+ "1|1|name|2.5\n"
+ "1|1|name|2.5\n"
+ "1|2|name|2.5\n"
+ "[category]\n"
+ "1|food\n"
+ "2|meat\n"
+ "[store]\n"
+ "1|A\n"
+ "2|b\n";

var splitted = s.split(/\[([^\]]+)\]/g);

/*
    splitted = [
        "",
        "product",
        "\n1|1|name|2.5\n1|1|name|2.5\n1|2|name|2.5\n",
        "category",
        "\n1|food\n2|meat\n",
        "store",
        "\n1|A\n2|b\n"
    ]
*/

var result = {};
for(var i = 1 ; i < splitted.length ; i += 2) {
    result[splitted[i]] = splitted[i + 1].trim().split("\n");
}

/*
    result = {
        product :["1|1|name|2.5", "1|1|name|2.5", "1|2|name|2.5"],
        category:["1|food", "2|meat"],
        store   :["1|A", "2|b"]
    }
*/
```